# can in-browser flash be stopped from interacting with the network, either via configuration or through firewall (on Windows)?

Tags: windows, flash, firewall, internet-security

suppose I want to allow loading of SWF files (like ads, simple games etc) but I don't want to allow them transmit info back to the server. How do I go about doing this on Windows? Is there such security setting in flash player itself? Or can this be accomplished via an existing firewall?

Comment: Each instance of communication to remote servers would have a port number but you could set windows firewall from making outgoing connections for flash if you know what executable it runs. Otherwise try global settings: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Comment: It's worth mentioning though that many Flash applications rely on communication with servers to function correctly.

Comment: @john, what you say seems to make sense, but it is not clear to me how would the firewall even distinguish web traffic from flash player from that of the browser. After all, it seems that nowadays flash player runs in the same process as the browser. Perhaps for Firefox this could be done by a codebase hack that monitors browser's own web interaction so that everything else is flash, but this sounds complex.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. It might help others to know why you want to block this communication.